# Select case string comparison

Tags: .net, strings, vb.net

I have a select case that checks against a string variable.  It's starting to get large and I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Here is a sample of the `Select Case` statement:

```
Select Case Param.ToLower
    Case "dashboard_home_vm"
        Return _Locator.DashboardHome_VM
    Case "job_list_vm"
        Return _Locator.JobList_VM
    Case "job_add_vm"
        Return _Locator.JobAdd_VM
    Case "client_add_vm"
        Return _Locator.ClientAdd_VM
    Case "client_list_vm"
        Return _Locator.ClientList_VM
    Case "client_report_vm"
        Return _Locator.ClientReport_VM
    Case "employee_add_vm"
        Return _Locator.EmployeeAdd_VM
    Case "employee_certification_vm"
        Return _Locator.EmployeeCertification_VM
    Case "employee_list_vm"
        Return _Locator.EmployeeList_VM
    Case "employee_report_vm"
        Return _Locator.EmployeeReport_VM
    Case "employee_role_vm"
        Return _Locator.EmployeeRole_VM
    Case "employee_timeslip_vm"
        Return _Locator.EmployeeTimeslip_VM
    Case "product_add_vm"
        Return _Locator.ProductAdd_VM
    Case "product_category_vm"
        Return _Locator.ProductCategory_VM
    Case "product_list_vm"
        Return _Locator.ProductList_VM
    Case "product_type_vm"
        Return _Locator.ProductType_VM
    Case "product_unit_vm"
        Return _Locator.ProductUnit_VM
    Case "tracking_stock_vm"
        Return _Locator.TrackingInStock_VM
    Case "tracking_list_vm"
        Return _Locator.TrackingList_VM
    Case "tracking_site_vm"
        Return _Locator.TrackingOnSite_VM
    Case "vendor_add_vm"
        Return _Locator.VendorAdd_VM
    Case "vendor_list_vm"
        Return _Locator.VendorList_VM
    Case "vendor_report_vm"
        Return _Locator.VendorReport_VM
    Case Else
        Return Nothing
End Select
```

This actual list will be about 50 - 80 comparisons.  Is this the fastest way to do this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A classic solution to this problem is to use a data table - in your case probably in form of a dictionary. It depends of what type your values are - I assume they are some sort of view models? I'm also going to assume they have a common base class:

One time setup:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, ViewModelBase)
dict.Add("dashboard_home_vm", _Locator.DashboardHome_VM)
...
```

You can look them up simply by

```
Dim vm As ViewModelBase
If (dict.TryGetValue(Param.ToLower, vm)) Then
    return vm
End If
return Nothing
```

Adding a new view model would be achieved by simply adding a new entry to the dictionary.

Comment: awesome, I knew there had to be cleaner way, also bonus points for correctly guessing that I was referring to view models.  You even got the base class name right!

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary is definitely the way to go, but I think you can improve on /u/ChrisWue's answer.

Since I'm assuming you don't need to change it at runtime, you can use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) to create it in a single syntactic line. Like this:

```vb
Private ReadOnly viewModelLocator As New Dictionary(Of String, ViewModelBase) From {
                    {"dashboard_home_vm", _Locator.DashboardHome_VM},
                    {"job_list_vm", _Locator.JobList_VM},
                    {"job_add_vm", _Locator.JobAdd_VM}
                 }
```

Initializing it without using the `Add` method is quicker and allows us to mark this as `ReadOnly` for clarity.  Plus fitting it into a single line means we can initialize it outside of the flow of our constructor.

Don't just call it `dict` since we already know it's a dictionary from it's type.  Use a nice name to describe what *this particular* dictionary is doing, like `viewModelLocator`.

When using [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When this method returns, it contains the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the value parameter

Since you want to return `Nothing` if the key is not found and the associated value when it is, and since the *default value* of your ViewModelBase is Nothing, you don't need to specifically handle the the boolean returned by `TryGetValue`.  You should add another function to read the dictionary that looks like this:

```vb
Function GetViewModel(ByVal viewModelName) As ViewModelBase
    Dim vm As ViewModelBase
    viewModelLocator.TryGetValue(viewModelName.ToLower, vm)
    Return vm
End Function
```

Again, don't call this `Param`.  Use good variable names like `viewModelName` or something similar.

---

If you had fewer cases you needed to run through, and you were only returning a single item per case, I think it's slightly more readable to put the entire case on the same line by using the colon (`:`) as the [VB line terminator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxda45fy.aspx#sectionToggle1) like this:

```vb
Select Case Param.ToLower
    Case "dashboard_home_vm" : Return _Locator.DashboardHome_VM
    Case "job_list_vm" : Return _Locator.JobList_VM
    Case "job_add_vm" : Return _Locator.JobAdd_VM
    '....
End Select
```

Comment: You can mark it as `ReadOnly` whether or not you use the collection initializer syntax. `ReadOnly` marks the variable `viewModelLocator` as not being able to be assigned to after construction. However, it does not make the contents read-only as `Add`, `Remove`, etc. can be called on it. That being said, I recommend `ReadOnly` for that purpose: prevents accidental re-assignment.

Answer (score -1):

Cant you just use the output of param.tolower after _locator.?

```
return _locator.(Param.ToLower)
```

try if that works